# jQuery auto submit

Tags: jquery

I have 3 file inputs for uploading files as follows,

```
A File : <input type="file" name="AFile" id="AFile" />
B File: <input type="file" name="BFile" id="BFile" />
C File : <input type="file" name="CFile" id="CFile" />
```

I've used the following jQuery function to auto upload the 3 files when selected,

```
$("#AFile" && "#BFile" && "#CFile").change(function() { 
document.getElementById("UploadFile").submit();
});
```

The above function works fine only if `AFile`, `BFile` and `CFile` are selected in order and fails if selected out of the above order.

That is say if, `CFile` is selected first and then `AFile` the `UploadFile` gets auto submitted even before the third file (B file) is selected. The same error happens in any case of selectiong apart from the above success case.

```
AFile BFile CFile - Form with three files submitted
AFile CFile - form gets submitted even before third selection could be made, the same happens for any case apart from the A, B, C selection case.
```

Logically,

```
A B C AND
1 1 1  1
1 1 0  0
1 0 1  0
1 0 0  0
0 1 1  0
0 1 0  0
0 0 1  0
0 0 0  0
```

but this is not happening.

How do I solve this bug?

PS: I feel making 3 separate submission to the servlet or describing multiple selection cases using an or(||) is not a great way to do it, please post only if you have any other answer apart from these two approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the problem is that in `HTML` && doesn't make any sense, and `,` is for OR and  is for AND.

But again something like,

```
$("#LeftFile #RightFile #ConfigFile")
```

would mean, A and B and C instead of what I want as A and (B and C)  as jQuery does not support operator overloading, and hence would not work and would consider only C.

So, finally I've used a counter to satisfy my condition that I must stick to single submit

```
var files = $("#LeftFile, #RightFile, #ConfigFile").change(function() {
var count = files.filter(function(){
    return this.value.length;
}).length;
if(count == files.length)
    {
        document.getElementById("UploadFile").submit();     
    }

});
```

Now this works irrespective of order of selection.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make them separate:

```
$("#AFile").change(function() { 
    document.getElementById("UploadFile").submit();
}); 
$("#BFile").change(function() { 
    document.getElementById("UploadFile").submit();
}); 
$("#CFile").change(function() { 
    document.getElementById("UploadFile").submit();
});
```

Alternatively, you could check if all 3 files have been selected before submitting.

Comment: THank you for your answer, but I don't wanna have 3 separate submissions to the servlet

Comment: OK, then within the `$("#AFile" && "#BFile" && "#CFile").change(function() { 
document.getElementById("UploadFile").submit();
});`, you should check if all three input's have a value (file selected) and only submit if all three do.

Comment: I think that is what I wrote, please check my question properly.

Comment: Yeah, except you added that after I posted my answer. I don't think a vote down due to a change in the question is really called for.

Comment: Nah! My Original question consisted of the approach. YOu can check the edit history if you want to.. all I added is that logical explanation.

Comment: Please check this link which consists of what I edited and what my original question consisted of http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23336119/revisions

Comment: Your original question did not state that you did not want to make 3 separate submissions; yes, it included `"#AFile" && "#BFile" && "#CFile"` but not comment that you did not want to split those. Thanks, but I read your original question.

Comment: and btw I didn't downvote your answer. You took time to answer my question, and I wouldn't ever downvote it.

Comment: Fine, no worries. It was a general comment, not directed at you. Thank you (or whoever), upvoted it again.

Comment: I feel answer given by martincarlin87 would work, I am trying it out

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input:file").change(function () {

    var valid = true;

    $("input:file").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "")
            valid = false;
    });
    if (valid)
        $("#UploadFile").submit();
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/mu34j/1/

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fiddle I made - http://jsfiddle.net/wnq5h/

**jQuery**

```
$('input[type="file"]').change(function() {
    var valid = 1;

    $('input[type="file"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            valid = 0;
        }
    });

    if (valid === 1) {
        alert('submitting'); // $("#UploadFile").submit();
    } else {
        alert('not all files selected'); // return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have 2 other inputs apart from the 3 above inputs but I want to submit only these 3??

Comment: hmm, easiest way would be to remove the 2 other inputs from the form so that they are not included in the form data, or, you could remove the `name` property from those inputs. The alternative is if you were using AJAX to submit the form, you could choose which inputs to submit.

Comment: The problem is not with the form submission, the problem is with `$('input[type="file"]').each(function()` and I don't think removing other input forms would be a good solution.

Comment: you mean the selector? I assume you know how to use the correct selector? Just change `$(input[type="file"])` to `$(#yourformid input[type="file"])`

Comment: I don't know what you need then, you have two other inputs but you don't want to submit them, then what I mentioned in my comment would work (did you read the part about the `name` attribute?). If that's not what  you mean then try and rephrase your requirements a little.

Comment: Thnak You, I'll try it out and will keep you posted.